# How to get stored data in picklist values by using trigger?

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex, datatrigger

I have picklist field name is Type__c and in that values are Disbursal and payment, where Disbursal=1000 & Payment is =5000.
My requirement is when I choose disbursal I need a trigger and show the values of disbursal of 1000 and the same as payment need to show if I chose a payment.it throws error on it[image]

```
   My trigger code:

    trigger TransactionAct on Loan_Transaction__c (after insert) {
    List<Timeline_Event__c> timelineList=new List<Timeline_Event__c>();
    TimelineEventController tobj=new TimelineEventController();
    ITimelineEventController timeAssignCtrl=new TimelineEventController();
    IController conCtrl=new contactController();
    
    for( Loan_Transaction__c trans :Trigger.New){
        Timeline_Event__c tEvent=new Timeline_Event__c();
               string rtype='', subtitle='';
        
        if( Trigger.isAfter){
                sObject c=conCtrl.getById(trans.Loan__c);

            if(trans.Type__c=='Disbursal'){
                subtitle=rtype+'Disbursal of';
  tEvent=(Timeline_Event__c)timeAssignCtrl.timelineTrigger(trans ,'trans Disbural','',subtitle,'insert','trans' );
         timelineList.add(tEvent);
            }    
            else if(trans.Type__c=='Payment'){
                 subtitle=rtype+'Payment of';
                 tEvent=(Timeline_Event__c)timeAssignCtrl.timelineTrigger(trans,'trans Payment','',subtitle,'insert','tarns'  );
                 timelineList.add(tEvent);
            }
            
            
        }
 
          }
   tobj.createMany(timelineList);  

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check method `timelineTrigger` in Apex class `ITimelineEventController`. Either this method doesn't exist or you are passing incorrect parameters.

Comment: Correct, the OP is passing a Log_Transaction__c and five strings but there is no method `timelineTrigger` that receives those parameters.